# Handles on pots loosen over time - can I loctite them?

Tags: food-safety, equipment

The handles on my pots loosen over time and I have to occasionally tighten the screw that attaches them.

Is there any reason why I can't or shouldn't use Loctite (screw locking compound) on them to secure them?

And if that's the case, why not send them from the factor pre-Loctited?

Comment: The bigger question here might be why some manufacturers use screw-on handles rather than welded handles or some other non-hardware method. An indicator of low cost cookware? To me it does not make sense, since the screws either come loose or rust to the point where you cannot tighten them.

Comment: These are Fissler pots, so not cheap. :-(

Comment: Just my guess at a possibility, maybe it is wrong. From an assembly point of view, using hardware would be easier with lower equipment costs. I am not sure if Loctite would be sturdy enough under the operating conditions of cookware. My problem has been with screw rusting, as water gets into the exposed surfaces. Loctite would not help this.

Comment: @user3169 : it could also be seen as a sign of longer-term durability, if it meant you could change/replace handles over the long term, rather than have to dispose of the whole pot or pan.

Comment: I've seen chefs screw off the handles of pans in order to finish the dish in the oven. I think some pans are designed for the handle to easily screw on/off.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use Loctite 2046 which is food safe. They list deep fryers as a possible application, so it should also work on a cooking pot.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming to this old thread via a search: I haven't tried this, but it might be worth trying a compression washer. I'm not very hopeful, not on technical grounds but because if that worked, the manufacturers would surely do it; repeated heating and cooling are a sure-fire way to loosen things. There are several different types of compression washer (see Wikipedia Washer(hardware), section Spring and locking washers); I don't know which would be best.

If trying Loctite I wouldn't be worried about food-grade types, it's well out of the way of food (unless the screw is actually inside the pan, which I've never seen).

Answer (score 1):

If the handles in question are made of plastic, you would not be able to get the new ones if the old ones break off because screw held with loctite(red) doesn't come off easily.